# How to intercept a bootstrap-hover-dropdown choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to intercept a choice made from a dropdown menu. This menu is made with https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown but that certainly doesn't change the basics.
My HTML code is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group text">
            <label class=" control-label" for="comment">Comment :</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control " placeholder="Free comment" id="" value="" /> 
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success add_language dropdown-toggle"
                        id="add_language-1"
                        title="Add a language"
                        data-toggle="dropdown"
                        data-hover="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="1">English</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="2">Spanish</a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex="3">German</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is what I figure out to intercept the selection, but that doesn't work and to be more precise, I'm in fact interested by the tabindex's value:

```
$( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdownHover();

    $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#dropdown-menu').selected();
        alert(value);
    });
}
```

In fact the onclick is even not called.
What is my mistake here?
Here is the corresponding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caBBAlainB/7n0e2cwe/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with a select element, you can mark up your menu like this:

```
<select class="dropdown-menu" multiple>
  <option value="1">English</option>
  <option value="2">Spanish</option>
  <option value="3">German</option>
</select>
```

then pull out the value using [jQuery's val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($('.dropdown-menu').val());
  }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks, your code certainly works but my main problem here is that the onClick seems not being fired. Don't know if the bootstrap-hover-dropdown library is responsible of that or not....

Comment: Sorry, it works, my problem was certainly due to a syntax error. thanks.